# creating a queue in JBoss MQ

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm trying to call send a message to a JBoss MQ queue but it seems the queue is not bounded.

I use the following code to send the message :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jnp.interfaces");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://127.0.0.1:1299");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(properties);

log.info("Looking up queue");
Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("Queue/testQueue");
```

I have a file "" located in deploy/jms/jbossmq-destinations-service.xml with the following entry :

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue" 
  name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=MyQueue"> 
</mbean>
```

but I get the following exception when trying to send the message :

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Queue not bound
```

when starting the JBoss server, I get this error, maybe that's the cause(how to solve it ?) :

```
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jmx-console.war/ deployment failed
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:379)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy46.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
    at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy47.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy10.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16:43:55,276 ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not start deployment: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jmx-console.war/
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jmx-console.war/ deployment failed
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:379)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy46.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
    at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy47.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy10.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16:43:55,337 INFO  [EARDeployer] Init J2EE application: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/AfrikBrain.GestUserApp.ear
16:43:55,560 INFO  [EjbModule] Deploying GestUtilisateur
16:43:55,642 INFO  [ProxyFactory] Bound EJB Home 'GestUtilisateur' to jndi 'ejb/Utilisateur'
16:43:55,644 INFO  [EJBDeployer] Deployed: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/tmp/deploy/tmp56029AfrikBrain.GestUserApp.ear-contents/AfrikBrain.GestUserEJB.jar
16:43:55,679 INFO  [EARDeployer] Started J2EE application: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/AfrikBrain.GestUserApp.ear
16:43:55,711 INFO  [EARDeployer] Init J2EE application: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/AfrikBrain.Mesutilitaires.Report.v3.1.ear
16:43:55,943 INFO  [EjbModule] Deploying GestEtat
16:43:55,982 INFO  [ProxyFactory] Bound EJB Home 'GestEtat' to jndi 'ejb/common/GestEtat'
16:43:55,984 INFO  [EJBDeployer] Deployed: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/tmp/deploy/tmp56030AfrikBrain.Mesutilitaires.Report.v3.1.ear-contents/AfrikBrain.Mesutilitaires.Report.v3.1.jar
16:43:56,040 INFO  [EARDeployer] Started J2EE application: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/AfrikBrain.Mesutilitaires.Report.v3.1.ear
16:43:56,110 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:

--- Packages waiting for a deployer ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@8f7fa105 { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/DataTransfer/Config/DataTransfer.properties }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/DataTransfer/Config/DataTransfer.properties
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991036052
  lastModified: 1258991036045
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@642f1c3c { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/data/configuration/ResCodeOra.properties }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/data/configuration/ResCodeOra.properties
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991036087
  lastModified: 1258991036080
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@4a365deb { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/data/configuration/config.properties }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/data/configuration/config.properties
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991036096
  lastModified: 1258991036094
  mbeans:

--- Incompletely deployed packages ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@6248b8b2 { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/ }
  deployer: MBeanProxyExt[jboss.web:service=WebServer]
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/ deployment failed
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/web.xml
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991001681
  lastModified: 1251969105078
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@fd61172b { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/ }
  deployer: MBeanProxyExt[jboss.web:service=WebServer]
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/ deployment failed
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/WEB-INF/web.xml
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991003905
  lastModified: 1251969103031
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@5ad1bb75 { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jbossws.sar/jbossws-context.war }
  deployer: MBeanProxyExt[jboss.web:service=WebServer]
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/tmp/deploy/tmp55995jbossws-context-exp.war/ deployment failed
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jbossws.sar/jbossws-context.war
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991004635
  lastModified: 1258991004524
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@c1985de5 { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/ }
  deployer: MBeanProxyExt[jboss.web:service=WebServer]
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/ deployment failed
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/WEB-INF/web.xml
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991005026
  lastModified: 1251969105593
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@35cb6f00 { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jmx-console.war/ }
  deployer: MBeanProxyExt[jboss.web:service=WebServer]
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jmx-console.war/ deployment failed
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jmx-console.war/WEB-INF/web.xml
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991034942
  lastModified: 1251969105812
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@8f7fa105 { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/DataTransfer/Config/DataTransfer.properties }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/DataTransfer/Config/DataTransfer.properties
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991036052
  lastModified: 1258991036045
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@642f1c3c { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/data/configuration/ResCodeOra.properties }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/data/configuration/ResCodeOra.properties
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991036087
  lastModified: 1258991036080
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@4a365deb { url=file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/data/configuration/config.properties }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/data/configuration/config.properties
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1258991036096
  lastModified: 1258991036094
  mbeans:

--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=ROOT.war,id=1648933042
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/ deployment failed

ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=invoker.war,id=-43968725
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/ deployment failed

ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=jbossws-context.war,id=1523694453
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/tmp/deploy/tmp55995jbossws-context-exp.war/ deployment failed

ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=jbossmq-httpil.war,id=-1046979099
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/ deployment failed

ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=web-console.war,id=131310982
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/ deployment failed
  I Depend On:
    jboss.admin:service=PluginManager

ObjectName: jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=DataTransferQueue
  State: FAILED
  Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null object name

ObjectName: jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=MyQueue
  State: FAILED
  Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null object name

ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=jmx-console.war,id=902524672
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jmx-console.war/ deployment failed

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=jmx-console.war,id=902524672
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/AFRIKBRAIN/jboss-4.2.1.GA/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/AfrikBrain/deploy/jmx-console.war/ deployment failed

ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=jbossws-context.war,id=1523694453
  State: FAILE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to add the destinationManager to the queue declaration. Try this:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue" 
  name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=MyQueue"> 
  <depends optional-attribute-name="DestinationManager">jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager</depends>
</mbean>
```

Which defines where jboss will persist your queue (by default it uses the one defined in hsqldb-jdbc2-service.xml).

I think that you are having that exception because you are looking with a wrong JNDI name. I think you have to do

`Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("queue/MyQueue");`

pay attention that it's *queue* (lowercase) plus the name you gave to the queue in the xml file "name=MyQueue"

Comment: actually, I found the culprit. the error has to do with my jboss directory. I used a different one and I could successfully bound to the queue. it seems while starting, the errors encountered by JBoss prevent him from binding the queue. this JBoss server seems to require me to change it after every while.